# How to pass driver-specific options to QgsVectorFileWriter?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I would like to add layer to .gdb according to  ( [PyQGIS cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html)) example:

```py
# Write to an ESRI GDB file
save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
save_options.driverName = "FileGDB"
# if no geometry
save_options.overrideGeometryType = QgsWkbTypes.Unknown
save_options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
save_options.layerName = 'my_new_layer_name'
transform_context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
gdb_path = "testdata/my_example.gdb"
error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer,
                                                gdb_path,
                                                transform_context,
                                                save_options)
if error[0] == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
  print("success!")
else:
  print(error)
```

and it works great, yet I can't figure out how to pass additional option to put my layer in a certain dataset. In [driver's documentation there are Layer Creation Options](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html#layer-creation-options) and one of them is `FEATURE_DATASET`, but

```py
save_options.FEATURE_DATASET = 'abc'
```

is not working (gives no error, but the layer gets saved outside of any dataset, no matter if given existing one or not).

What is the proper way to pass this additional parameter?

Comment: Looking at the API, I'd say `save_options.layerOptions = ['FEATURE_DATASET=abc']` should work. Unfortunately, I'm not able to build FileGDB support currently, so can not confirm whether that actually works.

Comment: It works! Thank you and please provide an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL Driver specific parameters can be passed using the attribute [`layerOptions`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter_1_1SaveVectorOptions.html#a43f054fdb00dfd6146cf92696f96eed5). It accepts a list of string values in the standard `KEY=VALUE` format that is listed on the GDAL documentation pages.

So in your example case it would be:

```
save_options.layerOptions = ['FEATURE_DATASET=abc']
```